# javascript object using 'this'

Tags: javascript, object

Part of  my code

```
var tablo = {
    tablo_id: 0,
    retrivedData: 1234,
    getData: function() {
      var xhr;
      var data = "aranan=" + document.getElementById('aranan').value;

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            this.retrivedData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(this.retrivedData); //first
          }
        }

        xhr.open("POST", "listele.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send(data);
      },

      setData: function() {
        console.log(this.retrivedData); //Second  
      }
    }
}
function u() {
  tablo.getData();
  tablo.setData();
}
```

When I run function u() first console.log work  but seconde one does not work ,second  only returns 1234 . I use function u()  in button onclick event

Comment: You need to define what "work" and "does not work" mean. Provide expected output and actual output, plus any error messages if there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, you are sending async AJAX Request, in javascript by default all ajax requests are async. Async request won't wait for response, it will send the AJAX request and will continue it's invocation (which is indeed a feature) because meanwhile server is responsing, you can execute other code on javascript

So actual sequence of your execution is
function getData() -> send request -> function setData() -> console.log("second") -> receive response -> console.log("first")

You can try below code, and let me know whether it solves your problem or not

```
var tablo = {
    tablo_id: 0,
    retrivedData: 1234,
    getData: function() {
      var xhr;
      var data = "aranan=" + document.getElementById('aranan').value;
      var that = this;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            that.retrivedData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("First :",that.retrivedData); //first
            that.setData();
          }

        }

        xhr.open("POST", "listele.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send(data);

      },

      setData: function() {
          console.log("Second :",this.retrivedData); //Second  
        },

    }
}

function u() {
  tablo.getData();
  //tablo.setData();
}
```

Comment: so how can I change this situation

Comment: @GungorCelik: it depends on what you want to achieve, would you be more clear with your question, then I could help you...

Comment: I just transfer data  from getData function  to SetData function that has codes for filling table cells with loop

Comment: @GungorCelik: Okay then you need to call that function once you receive response, so on readystate change you can call a callback function

Comment: I understand but I do not know how I do it

Comment: @GungorCelik : Did my answer helped you?

Comment: :163 Uncaught TypeError: this.setData is not a function

Comment: @GungorCelik: Updated the answer a little bit have a look at it, and let me know whether it works..

Comment: now   returns 1234

Comment: That is totally strange it is working for me, would you show me all console dumps... @GungorCelik

Comment: I forget to change  one "this" to that now work  thankss

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the ´this´ scope, you should save the reference to `this` (`var _this = this`) before of defining `xhr.onreadystatechange = ...` and use it into the callback instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is caused by the fact, that `this` in a callback does not point to the object, but rather to `window`. So essentially, you are setting `window.retrivedData` instead of the object's `retrievedData`. To solve that problem, you have the following options:

1) Bind the correct `this` to the callback by using:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // [...]
}.bind(this)
```

2) Manually set `this` by using:

```
var self = this;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // here do not use "this" but "self" instead
}
```

3) Use the fat-arrow notation of ES6:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    // [...]
}
```

But be aware that ES6 is not (fully) supported by most browsers, yet. You need to transpile your code, for example, with Babel.

Also not that it is "retrieved" and not "retrived".